# Is there a rule of thumb for reading AGL vs MSL?

Tags: altitude

Recently, I read that as it pertains to directions: if you read it, it's true, if you hear it, it's magnetic. This is mostly correct, one edge case though is runways are *written/drawn* with magnetic direction.

Is there a similar rule of thumb for altitudes in MSL vs AGL?

Comment: I can’t say I understand what you are talking about.  AGL ie equal to MSL reading minus local field elevation directly below the aircraft.  Radar altimeters display altitudes in AGL.

Comment: I think the answer to the question is simply, "no".

Comment: @CarloFelicione I just mean that in aviation, there are some things reported in AGL and some in MSL, in the same way that some directions are reported in "true" and some "magnetic". I was curious if there was a similar rule of thumb but it seems that there isnt

Comment: You can’t generalize about magnetic/true. The written/spoken only applies to wind direction in weather reports. The one exception is wind direction reported in PIREPs where it is reported as magnetic whether is is written or spoken. It does not apply to charts and ATC. Airways are based on VORs which use magnetic direction.  Approach and departure charts all use magnetic direction. Even RNAV charts show magnetic direction. And ATC will always give you headings based on magnetic headings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know that you can generalize, but there is a general tendency to report things as MSL unless you are close enough to the ground that you might hit them.

For example, on VFR charts in the US, manmade obstacles show both MSL with AGL in parentheses below it. If you are flying along and there is a radio tower, it makes sense that you might want to know how high above the surrounding terrain it is.The highest point in the terrain on the other hand only shows MSL.

NOTAMs for obstacles around an airport show the AGL first and then MSL. When you are doing your pre-flight planning, knowing how high you need to climb above the field is probably of more use to you than knowing the MSL value. e.g. if an obstacle two miles from the field is 300’ AGL you know that you need to climb more than 150’ per nm in order to avoid it.

Traffic pattern altitudes are usually 800 or 1,000’ AGL but expressed as MSL. It’s good to know for planning purposes how high above the ground you will be, but (in the US at least) you use MSL on your altimeter to fly the pattern.

IFR charts all depict altitudes in MSL. Approach charts (US TPPs) do show AGL below the MSL values. You can always calculate the AGL value from the MSL and field elevation, but having it on the chart gives you a heads-up as to how high above the field you will be if you fly an approach to minimums.

Weather follows the same general principle of “the closer you are to the ground, the more likely you are to be interested in AGL”. If you listen to the ATIS, you are given ceilings and cloud cover in AGL. However, when planning your flight, winds aloft are given as MSL. That makes a lot of sense since the forecast is for a wide area where the terrain can vary tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

Simply this: there is no such thing as "altitude AGL". *Altitude* is always AMSL, *height* is always AGL, and *flight levels* are always with reference to setting 1013 on your altimeter subscale.

Whenever anyone gives you a level, they should explicitly call it an "altitude", "height", or "flight level". The exception is if they say something like "3000 ft on QNH 1004", which is always an altitude; in the UK, the inverse is true for "1000 ft on QFE 1002".

Comment: QFE heights aren't height AGL, it's height above an aerodrome reference location. This is important when there's terrain. Ideally this is height above runway, but that may not be true.

Comment: That's true, but you would usually only be on QFE in the vicinity of the aerodrome anyway. Since it's only a local term I don't feel the need to explain it too much.